# Infinite descent argument in the case of $x^5+y^5=z^5$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, infinite-descent

Euler proved that:
$$2u(u^2+3v^2)=(2a(a^2+3b^2))^3$$ had no non-trivial solutions.

Several other mathematicians have proven that: $$x^5+y^5=z^5$$
Using a similar argument, it is easy to see when $x$ and $y$ are both odd that the above equation is equivalent to $$2u(u^4+10(uv)^2+5v^4)=z^5$$ when we set $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$.

I wonder if we were able to show in the latter case that there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that:$$z=2a(a^4+10(ab)^2+5b^4)$$ How could one conclude by infinite descent that the above equation has no non trivial solutions?
I know it's hypothetical but it's worth inquiring. Stay safe everyone!

Comment: I wonder if your Question has gotten a bit mangled in the process of editors applying math formatting.  The title refers to an instance of Fermat's Last Theorem (with exponent $n=5$) but the body of the Question lacks a direct reference to this.  Finally the penultimate paragraph asks whether "there exists and integer $N$ such that" $N=2a(a^4 + 10(ab)^2 + 5b^4)$.  The use of $N$ may relate to the previous paragraph, where $N$ appears to the fifth power, but leaves this Reader confused as to which "above equation has no non trivial solution".

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. I edited it. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: @Num Thcurious: Dear friend, if in three centuries and half (plus $8$) that many mathematicians payed passionated attention to FLT, one of them  would have found a proof for exponent $5$ using the blessed infinite descent then would have published it in a paper edited by high-level editors.

Comment: I guess in the last equation should be $z^5$ instead of $z$.